# сможет ли человек знающий основы js выучить react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

сможет ли человек знающий основы js выучить react? 
или вообще  нужно учить react?

Comment: нет, не сможет.

Comment: а сможет vue js?

Comment: сможет-то сможет, но есть ли резон ? когда сейчас уже есть библиотека, которая в 30 раз производительнее реакта (и только начал набирать обороты). Я конечно понимаю, что 3 столпа(реакт, вью и ангуляр) еще  долго будут держаться на рынке. Тут уж нужно определиться с целями - за новыми технологиями или изучать то, чего требует рынок сейчас )

Comment: @Алекс Данилин, и что это за библиотека? Vanilla JS?

Comment: @Node_pro svelte.js

Comment: @АлексДанилин, не уверен, что оно будет быстрее в 30 раз... Да и тут вопрос в другом... Немного схожая система с Vue.js

Comment: @Node_pro уже делали сравнение - в 30 раз(реакт) и 50 (вью). Вес мал, комьюнити тоже, пока что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с React потребуется изучить целый стек технологий, потому что это не язык программирования а фреймворк.
Начать нужно с установки nodejs, узнать для чего нужен npm
Затем git, он понадобится в любом случае
Далее создаем React проект (как это делается ? из чего состоит и так далее)
Предполагается что html и css в общих чертах уже освоены
Тут уже можно попробовать написать свой первый проект
SASS, Typescript, webpack по мере необходимости